# Python 3 byte string subscription

Tags: python-3.x

In Python, I am trying to byte string to handle some 8 bit character string. I find that byte string is not necessary behavior in a string like way. With subscript, it returns an number instead of a byte string of length 1.

```
In [243]: s=b'hello'

In [244]: s[1]
Out[244]: 101

In [245]: s[1:2]
Out[245]: b'e'
```

This makes it really difficult when I iterate it. For example, this code works with string but fail for byte string.

```
In [260]: d = {b'e': b'E', b'h': b'H', b'l': b'L', b'o': b'O'}

In [261]: list(map(d.get, s))
Out[261]: [None, None, None, None, None]
```

This breaks some code from Python 2. I also find this irregularity really inconcenient. Anyone has any insight what's going on with byte string?

Answer (score 0):

Byte strings store byte values in the range 0-255.  The `repr` of bytes is just a convenience to view them, but they are storing data not text.  Observe:

```
>>> x=bytes([104,101,108,108,111])
>>> x
b'hello'
>>> x[0]
104
>>> x[1]
101
>>> list(x)
[104, 101, 108, 108, 111]
```

Use strings for text.  If starting with bytes, decode them appropriately:

```
>>> s=b'hello'.decode('ascii')
>>> d = dict(zip('hello','HELLO'))
>>> list(map(d.get,s))
['H', 'E', 'L', 'L', 'O']
```

But if you want to work with bytes:

```
>>> d=dict(zip(b'hello',b'HELLO'))
>>> d
{104: 72, 108: 76, 101: 69, 111: 79}
>>> list(map(d.get,b'hello'))
[72, 69, 76, 76, 79]
>>> bytes(map(d.get,b'hello'))
b'HELLO'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply `decode` the string, get the element you want and encode it back :

```
s=b'hello'
t = s.decode()
print(t[1])             # This gives a char object   
print(t[1].encode())    # This gives a byte object
```